# std with arry index (not iterator) gives segmentation fault

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have defined a vector like this in the header file

```
class entry
{
   public: 
     int key;
     int next;
};
std::vector<entry *> TB;
```

in the cpp file, I wrote:

```
int s1, val;
s1 = 10; val = 2;
gh = (TB.size() % s1);
```

However when I want to write something to it, I get segmentation fault

```
TB[gh]->key = val;
```

What is the problem with the assignment?

Comment: Is there actually a valid pointer at `TB[gh]`?

Comment: I wonder where you learned that this should work...

Comment: no there is no element in TB. I am adding an element to that.

Comment: it's not a good practice to store pointers in std::vector. vector was developed to manage data by value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector has no elements. Use [`push_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) or [`insert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) to add elements to the vector:

```
entry* e = new entry();
e->key   = val;
e->next  = 0;

TB.push_back(e);          // Append to vector.
TB.insert(TB.begin(), e); // Insert at beginning of the vector.
```

When destroying the vector `TB` you must iterate over the elements and `delete` each individually (or use a smart pointer as the element type, such as `boost::shared_ptr<entry>` or `std::unique_ptr<entry>`).

You could provide a constructor(s) for `entry` to make the addition of an `entry` to `TB` more concise:

```
class entry
{
public: 
    entry(int a_key, int a_next = 0) : key(a_key), next(a_next) {}
    int key;
    int next;
};

TB.push_back(new entry(val));
TB.insert(TB.begin(), new entry(val));
```

Comment: that will push the data at the end of vector. Isn't possible to insert an element between elements?

Comment: You can use [std::vector::insert()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) to insert elements.

Answer (score 1):

1. The `TB` vector is empty, until you fill it with some pointers.
   E.g. `TB.resize(100);`.
2. The points in `TB` should point to valid addresses, i.e. some valid `entry` instances. E.g. `TB[0] = new entry();`.

So:

```
std::vector<entry *> TB(1);
TB[0] = new entry();
TB[0]->key = 42;
```

Comment: is it a must to specify TB size in `std::vector<entry *> TB(1);` ??

Comment: @mahmood It's only one of many. You can change the size anytime with `TB.resize(99);`, `TB.push_back(new entry());` etc.